# React-Native: How do I iterate Array of Arrays?

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have an array namely **resultinfo**  on every index there is an another array of student info , I want to replace these blank spaces as per my need:

```
resultInfo = [
    ["Alex" , "100" , "" , "" ],
    ["John" , "100" , "" , "" ],
    ["Peter" , "100" , "87" , "Pass" ]

]
```

my final **resultInfo** should look like this:

```
resultInfo = [
    ["Alex" , "100" , "47" , "Fail" ],
    ["John" , "100" , "77.5" , "Pass" ],
    ["Peter" , "100" , "87" , "Pass" ]

]
```

this is how I can access the array of first index:

```
resultInfo[0]
```

but how can I access the 3rd and 4th index of this array and the others?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean accessing the 3ed and 4th index inside the first array?
like:

```
resultInfo[0][3] = "47";
resultInfo[0][4] = "Fail";
resultInfo[1][3] = "77.5";
resultInfo[1][4] = "Pass";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are cleverer ways to handle the assignment, but this works:

```js
students.map(row => {
  row[0] = 'foo';
  row[1] = 'bar';
  row[2] = 'fizz';
  row[3] = 'buzz';
  return row;
});
```